# Azure Devops pipeline PublishBuildArtifact task Error Container could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to publish the build artifact in ADO pipeline, But end up with the issue

> Failed to upload artifact due to Container could not be found

Earlier the same script was working fine.

Only change I made was set **trigger: none** instead of **trigger: master** to stop CI build trigger and to run the pipeline manually.

yaml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Node.js Install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\OnlineBooking'

- script: |
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    node build.js
  displayName: 'Build Project'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'D:\a\1\s\temp\OnlineBooking\build\wap\build'
    Contents: 'OnlineBooking.zip'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'OnlineBooking'
```

Log:

```
Retry attempt 0. Exception: The container 16892178 could not be found. 
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9483088Z Intermittent failure attempting to call the restapis System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage] <AssociateAsync>b__0(). Retry attempt 1. Exception: The container 16892178 could not be found. 
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9484146Z Intermittent failure attempting to call the restapis System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage] <AssociateAsync>b__0(). Retry attempt 2. Exception: The container 16892178 could not be found. 
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9485219Z Fail to upload 'OnlineBooking/OnlineBooking.zip' due to 'The container 16892178 could not be found.'.
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9487833Z Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainerNotFoundException: The container 16892178 could not be found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.Client.FileContainerHttpClient.CreateItemForArtifactUpload(Int64 containerId, String itemPath, Guid scopeIdentifier, String artifactHash, Int64 fileLength, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.FileContainerServer.<>c__DisplayClass17_1.<<AssociateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.RetryHelper.Retry[T](Func`1 action, Func`2 timeDelayInterval, Func`2 shouldRetryOnException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.RetryHelper.Retry[T](Func`1 action, Func`2 timeDelayInterval, Func`2 shouldRetryOnException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.FileContainerServer.AssociateAsync(IAsyncCommandContext context, ConcurrentQueue`1 associateQueue, CancellationToken token)
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9490406Z 1 files failed to upload, retry these files after a minute.
2021-08-13T15:05:54.9490658Z Retry file upload after 60 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:00.0088101Z Retry file upload after 55 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:05.0568617Z Retry file upload after 50 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:10.1177816Z Retry file upload after 45 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:15.2097932Z Retry file upload after 40 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:19.7734672Z Retry file upload after 35 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:24.8510986Z Retry file upload after 30 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:29.9148313Z Retry file upload after 25 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:34.9479097Z Retry file upload after 20 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:40.0238444Z Retry file upload after 15 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:45.0731398Z Retry file upload after 10 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:50.1178453Z Retry file upload after 5 seconds.
2021-08-13T15:06:55.1807933Z Start retry 1 failed files upload.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample yaml(trigger: none), and it works fine with artifact task.
[image]

It's recommended to try again to check if it's a temporary issue.

If the issue persists, please confirm:

1. Change back to "trigger: master", enable CI trigger, will the pipeline work fine?
2. Does it work for another account(eg: organization owner)?
3. Tick "Enable system diagnostics" checkbox to get pipeline diagnostic log for a further checking.

Comment: Thanks Dharman for your reply. Have created another pipeline with Same yaml and it works and artifact is created. Issue with this specific pipeline only. Have to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for your update, @AjayElangovan!  For the specific pipeline, you can change to use another artifact task: "PublishPipelineArtifact@1", as doc mentioned, the "PublishBuildArtifacts@1" is deprecated. Please refer to doc for the details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you will use PublishPipelineArtifact@1. But the pipeline exit before this task ie. while building.